# test ad fs using a server name instead of the certificate cn

Tags: windows-server-2016, adfs, entra-id

I've just installed an AD FS 4 server farm and am trying to test connectivity to the proxy servers.

In the past (AD FS 2 and 3) I used to use https://fs.domain.name/adfs/fs/federationserverservice.asmx to test using the load balanced endpoint, and https://servername.domain.name/adfs/fs/federationserverservice.asmx to test each server.

On ADFS 4, however, this approach doesn't seem to work as when I try and use the server name I keep getting the message:

> Cannot securely connect to this page
>
> > This might be because the site uses outdated or unsafe TLS security settings. If this keeps happening, try contacting the website’s owner.

Internally, it does work fine using the load balanced endpoint that matches the certificate CN, and I can play around with the DNS settings to point to individual servers, but on the DMZ I need to be able to test each server and the load balanced endpoint before I change the DNS settings as I have users are logging on to the old server farm, and don't want to risk any service interruption.

Can anyone suggest any way around this?

Thanks in advance
Angelo

Answer (score 0):

Use IdpInitiatedSignon to validate ADFS is working. You can enable this by running the following commands on the primary node.

```
Set-AdfsProperties -EnableIdPInitiatedSignonPage $true
Get-AdfsProperties | Select-Object EnableIdpInitiatedSignonpage
```

You can then access it via https://fs.mydomain.com/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon and test signing in. Once you're done, be sure to disable it by running the same command with the flag set to $false. I get the same 503 for the federationserverservice url via WAP and I believe this is by design.